# Как реализовать шаблон SingleTon для сбора монет?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В скрипте PlayerInventory реализовать (шаблон) Singleton.Cделать начисление монеток путем обращения к Instance этого класса. Сбор монет реализовать в скрипте Player.
Ниже мой код:

```
public int CoinsCount;
private void Awake() 
{
    Debug.Log(Player.Instance.CoinsCount);
    
}
public static Player Instance {get;set;}

 
 }
```

А это скрипт Player:

```
 public class Coin
{
int CoinsCount;
public  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) 
{
    if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
    {
        CoinsCount++;
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
 }
}
```

Можете подсказать пожалуйста как реализовать это верно.Заранее спасибо.
Исправленная версия работает вот так [image: Предупреждения]

Код исправленной версии есть в комментарии к первому ответу на мой вопрос.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.3.php

Comment: Спасибо за полезную ссылочку,обязательно ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение, проверил у себя и всё работает. Значит , я заметил что у вас singleton PlayerInventory прикреплен к персонажу. Так быть НЕ должно. Singleton должен всегда висеть на пустом одиночном объекте (от этого и перевод singleton - одиночка). Нажимаете Create Empty и вешаете на него скрипт PlayerInventory, а скрипт Player так пусть и остается на герое.

```
public class PlayerInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int coinsCount{get;private set;} = 0;
    public static PlayerInventory Instance{get;private set;} = null;
    void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(Instance);
        }
        else Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    public void AddCoins(int count)
    {
        coinsCount += count;
    }
    public void AddCoins()
    {
        coinsCount++;
    }
}
```

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
   {
      if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
      {
         PlayerInventory.Instance.AddCoins();
         Debug.Log("Количество монет = " + PlayerInventory.Instance.coinsCount);
         Destroy(col.gameObject);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо,понял,сейчас попробую ваш вариант.

Comment: Добрый день всем,можете помочь с реализацией моего варианта?@aquaprogit
У меня просто не работает инициализация { get;set; } =0; и Public static PlayerInventory current { get; } =this;Вот мой вариант:
```

public class PlayerInventory
{ 
 public static Player CoinsCount {get;set;}
 
}
```

```
public int CoinsCount;
   public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
   {
      if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
      {
         CoinsCount++;
         Debug.Log("Количество монет = " + CoinsCount);
         Destroy(col.gameObject);
      }
   }

```

Comment: Я 3 года назад делал такую же игру как у вас , сейчас попробую найти ее и вставить свой код. и посмотрю что там не работает. Ожидайте до конца дня

Comment: Хорошо,жду вас.

Comment: Ещё одно важное замечание идея в том чтобы монетки собирались у игрока,а показывались в инвентаре.Ладно,больше ничего не пишу)Просто жду...

Comment: Я изменил ответ, проверил, в моем проекте все сработало идеально. Внимательно прислушайтесь к тому что я написал и у вас будет также)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное)Неимоверно помогли.